# Mark a point on a highcharts chart after that it has been drawn

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to achieve this: I gather data from various sources, and one of these has a value that I want to mark on the series that I draw (which is coming from a different source).

So file A has  `1.3.5.7.9,10` (my main series for the chart)
while file B has `5` (but it can be something different every day, this is the value to use as marker)

I would like to mark on the serie that I draw, using file A, the point that is in file B, and make it different (either bigger, or a different color; doesn't really matter)

I've extracted the data; done the work on the chart to find the value, but I don't know how you tell point [n] to change its appearance on the series

something like

```
var values=chart.yAxis[0].series[0].yData;
var thepoint=values[1]; 
[change thepoint and color it red or make it bigger]
```

Can this be done? I tried to look at the API but can't really find out how do you actually plug it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`point.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update), something like this:

```
var values=chart.yAxis[0].series[0].data;
var thepoint=values[1]; 
thepoint.update({ color: 'red', marker: { radius: 20 } });
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel, works perfectly. Is there also a way to add in the same way, the point to an arbitrary X value on the chart? Trying different solutions to display this specific point

Comment: Found also how to add the value to an arbitrary point: the addPoint function allow to specify X and Y values.

Comment: Or just use another series where you can set just this one specific point.

Comment: But with a series you can't decide where to set the point, right? I tried and it always add it to the first X value that it can find on the graph

Comment: Just add x-value when adding point: `series.addPoint([x, y])` and will work ;)